# Can you loop through a HashMap like you can in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, java-collections-api

Can you loop through a HashMap like you can in an ArrayList?
So if I have a class of Person:

```
public class Person
{
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Person(String name, int age)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }
}
```

Then had a class of Memberships, and using an array list I can ensure that the name isn't repeated:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Memberships
{
    private ArrayList<Person> members;

    public Memberships()
    {
        ArrayList<Person> members = new ArrayList<Person>();
    }

    public void addMember(String name, int age)
    {
        Person p = new Person(name, age);
        for (Person membs : members)
        {
            if (membs.getName().equals(name) && membs.getAge()==age)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        members.add(p);
    }
}
```

However if I wanted to use a hash map instead with the name and age:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> members = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

And then I wanted to do the same thing, and check the name and age aren't the same as another case, can I use a loop and check?

```
public class Memberships
{
    private HashMap<String, Integer> members;

    public Memberships()
    {
        members = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    }

    public void addMember(String name, int age)
    {
        members.put(name, age);
    }
}
```

I know this is slightly weird way of doing it, I'm just trying to understand HashMaps.

Ok so I then changed it, so that:

```
HashMap<Person, ID> members = new HashMap<Person, ID>();
```

And then I wanted to:

```
public void addMember(String name, int age)
{
    Person p = new Person (name, age);
    members.put(p, id);
    //**Say the id is a randomly generated number, that I don't really care about now
}
```

How would I check that the name and age of person p, isn't the same as another person in the members hashmap?

Comment: You won't need to loop, you can only have unique keys in a HashMap.

Comment: Do you just want name to be unique, or both name and age?

Comment: If you are to use Map interface and concrete classes... you need not check for same name... coz duplicate keys aren't allowed in Map... what is your condition for same name and different age?

Comment: First, you would never use a `List` for your first case - you would use a `Set`, which guarantees uniqueness and still has `O(1)` `add`. The whole point of a `HashMap`  is that keys are _unique_.

Comment: Ok so I've just changed it slightly, how about now?

Comment: Well, that random number... But see Set in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Why loop? You can simply test for the existence of a key:

```
if( members.containsKey( name ) ){
  // duplicate
}
```

You can iterate, though:

```
for( Map.Entry<String,Integer> e: members.entrySet() ){
     // use e.getKey(), e.getValue()
}
```

**Later**

Since Boris has raised the issue:

```
Map<String,Person> members
```

would be a way for mapping the name set to the Person set. If also age should help to distinguish Persons, Boris hint must be heeded: add hashCode and equals to Person (both using name and age to hashCode comp and comparison), and then you can do

```
Set<Person> members
```

and members.contains( p ) will tell you whether an equal Person is already a member.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Of the key String?

Comment: On the `Person` class - the OP wants to check the the `name` _and_ `age` are the not the same. So the OP needs to override `equals` and `hashCode` and use a `Set`.

Comment: You weave ahead ;-) Right now, the Map doesn't contain a Person. We don't know whether Person should be the key, when it's the name that matters. And if Person is the key - then what should be the value?

Comment: I think the OP is asking an XY problem - it's probably better to work out what exactly the OP _wants_ before answering. I suspect a `Set` it the answer.

Comment: I've tried to over-weave you and to cover all contingencies.

Comment: The OP how now changed the question, it seems the direction is the correct one...

Comment: @BoristheSpider It seems we've caught some flies before ;-)

Answer (score 1):

HashMap never has duplicated keys. I suggest to use ArrayList with Persons and implements an equal method in your Person class for check if there are duplicated objects in the ArrayList.

```
@Override public boolean equals(Object other) {
    boolean result = false;
    if (other instanceof Person) {
        Person otherPerson = (Person) other;
        result = (this.getName() == otherPerson.getName() && this.getAge() == otherPerson.getAge());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Overriding `equals` without `hashCode` is always a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

In a HashMap, the key can't be repeated, so you don't have to iterate over the Map for that purpose. In your `HashMap<String, Integer>`, the same name can't appear more than once.

There are methods to iterate over the keys (`keySet()`), values (`values()`) or entries (`entrySet()`) of the Map, but you don't need them for the purpose you stated.

Given you edit, you want to check if the new `Person` you created is contained in the Map :

```
public void addMember(String name, int age)
{
    Person p = new Person (name, age);
    if (members.containsKey (p) {
        members.put(p, id);
    }
}
```

For this to work, your Person class must override `hashCode` and `equals` methods. `equals` should return true if both the name and age are equal. `hashCode` should return an int value that depends on the `name` and `age` (so that if for two Persons p1 and p2 `p1.equals(p2)` then `p1.hashCode()==p2.hashCode()`).

Answer (score 0):

So for your arrayList solution, you can override the equals and hashcode for your Person class, so that you need not have to loop you can call the contains() method, by passing the Person object directly  created, like as follows `contains(new Person("name", "age"))` so it will easily find whether member present in the list or not.

You can use the same logic mentioned by you in your equals method implementation.

```
 if (membs.getName().equals(name) && membs.getAge()==age)
```

And if you want hashmap which I will advise not to go for but still, similarly you need not have to loop the hashmap as well, but can use containsKey to verify if same member is there or not or call get() to get the age of your member by passing the name. Hope it helps.